# Forme alterate di plurali irregolari: -a diventa -ina/-ona o -ine/-one?

Tags: grammar, nouns, grammatical-number

Ho un dubbio sulle forme alterate (ad es. diminutivo ed accrescitivo) di nomi col plurale irregolare in "-a" (braccia, ginocchia, dita) derivanti dal neutro di seconda declinazione latino.

Quando diminuiti o accresciuti, immaginando di usare la forma plurale in "-a" come base – tutti i miei esempi sono in realtà sovrabbondanti, ma la forma in "-i" non causa dubbi –, diventano "-ina/-ona" o "-ine/-one"?

Insomma:

> 1)
>
> *le bracci**a** → le bracc**ina**/bracci**ona***;
>
> *le dit**a** → le dit**ina**/dit**ona***

oppure

> 2)
>
> *le bracci**a** → le bracc**ine**/bracci**one***
>
> *le dit**a** → le dit**ine**/dit**one***

?

Io sono abbastanza convinto dell'opzione 2 ("ine/one"), ma conosco persone a cui viene più naturale l'opzione 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un articolo sul sito dell'Accademia della Crusca (["Plurale di *manina, braccino, ditino* e... *ovetto*"](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/plurale-di-manina-braccino-ditino-e-ovetto/1267) di Paolo D’Achille e Anna M. Thornton) copre l'argomento.

Analizzando il corpus storico di *La Repubblica* trova:

- 1 "braccini", 22 "braccine", 0 "braccina"
- 2 "lenzuolini", 1 "lenzuoline", 0 "lenzuolina"
- 9 "ditini", 8 "ditine", 3 "ditina"

Da Google Libri le abbondanze relative sembrano simili, ma sono ribaltate per "ossa", per cui prevale, tra quelle femminili, la forma in "-ina":

- 68 "braccini", 2040 "braccine", 65 "braccina"
- 801 "ditini", 218 "ditine", 167 "ditina"
- 3840 "ossicini", 101 "ossicine", 256 "ossicina"

Da un'esplorazione delle grammatiche, l'articolo della Crusca trova che o il tema non viene trattato, o, laddove lo fosse, che le forme in "-ina" sono indicate come "non ammissibili" o non elencate tra quelle ammissibili.

Concludendo, tra le forme in -i e quelle in -e trova sostanziale equivalenza:

> L’assenza di prescrizioni normative da un lato e la diffusione dei diminutivi di questo tipo più nel parlato colloquiale che nello scritto (e in genere nell’uso formale) spiegano perché l’uso non sia mai stato regolamentato e risulti ancora oscillante

mentre sconsiglia l'uso della forma in -a:

> le forme in -a non sembrano neppure oggi proprio del tutto impossibili. Sono però decisamente marginali, e dunque sconsigliabili.

Comment: Non riesco a capire la ragione dei downvote su questa risposta, che è infatti un riassunto di quello che dice l'Accademia della Crusca sull'argomento. Per favore, utenti che avete fatto questa valutazione, potresti cercare di essere più costruttivi e spiegare come, secondo voi, si potrebbe migliorare questa risposta o cosa non va nel suo contenuto? Si veda questo [post sul sito Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1337/) per più dettagli.

Answer (score 4):

Il senso dietro all'opzione 2 è che quando modifichi un nome, il suffisso si porta dietro tutta la sua 'declinazione': non si dice *Giovanni fa il birraia* perché viene da *birra*, ma è il suffisso *-aio* che stabilisce come formare i finali.

Questo è un principio grammaticale che viene direttamente dal latino: ad esempio, *corpus, -oris* è della III declinazione, ma se ci attacchi un suffisso *corpusculum, -i* diventa della II perché prende la declinazione propria del suffisso.

Quindi si dice "il braccino/i braccini", se si usa il maschile, e "le braccine" se si vuole tenere il plurale femminile.

(Con il solito disclaimer che se poi l'uso comune che si impone è diverso, il principio grammaticale vale solo la carta su cui è scritto --- quindi la tua risposta fa bene a considerare questo lato della questione.)

Comment: Credo che l'OP volesse chiedere se i plurali sovrabbondanti si trasferiscono a diminutivi o accrescitivi: il braccio/i bracci/le braccia e il braccino/i braccini/le braccina.

Comment: @egreg Non ti seguo: a me sembra abbastanza chiaro che la domanda sia "assumendo che uno voglia usare il femminile, si dice *le braccina* o *le braccine*". C'è addirittura una scelta tra opzione 1 e opzione 2 nella domanda.